# openpyxl Fetch value from excel and store in key value pair

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, openpyxl

Have written a python script that fetches the cell values and displays in a list row by row.

Here is my script:

```
 book = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_file_name)
 active = book.get_sheet_by_name(excel_file_name)

 def iter_rows(active): 
     for row in active.iter_rows(): 
         yield [cell.value for cell in row]

 res = list(iter_rows(active))
 for new in res:
     print new
```

> Output for the above script:  [state, country, code] [abc, xyz,
>   0][def, lmn, 0]
>
> I want output in below format:  [state:abc, country:xyz,
>   code:0][state:def, country:lmn, code:0]

Please note: I want to do this from openpyxl

Comment: sorry for the duplication. since the format of my previous question was not good.

Comment: Adding a generator with the same name as the worksheet method seems an unnecessary complication of the code. You probably want to extract the first row to get the keys and then use zip as @mike-muller suggests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
res = iter_rows(active)
keys = next(res)
for new in res:
    print dict(zip(keys, new))
```

`res` is an iterator. Therefore, `next(res)` gives the next element. In our case the keys for the dictionary. Iterating through the rest of `res`with the `for` loop, `dict()` creates a new dictionary for every element `new` using the same `keys` for all dictionaries. The function `zip()` combines two (or more) sequences in such a way, that it creates pairs with one element from each sequence. `dict()` uses one of these pairs as key and value for one new item and goes through of all pairs. For example, this:

```
dict(zip('abc', [1, 2, 3]))
```

results in this dictionary:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

Comment: Thanks Mike Muller! That worked for me. Please could you tell the logic!

Comment: Thanks again! Now its pretty clear with the example.